# Error when attempting to retrieve a matplotlib.lines.Line2D object property using getp

Tags: python

I have a list of handles to points that have been plotted using matplotlib.pyplot like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...

for i in range(0,len(z)):
    zh[i] = plt.plot(z[i].real, z[i].imag, 'go', ms=10)
    plt.setp(zh[i], markersize=10.0, markeredgewidth=1.0,markeredgecolor='k', markerfacecolor='g')
```

I'd also like to extract the XData and YData from the handles somewhere else in the code (z[i].real and z[i].imag would have changed by then). However, when I do this:

```
for i in range(1,len(zh)):
    print zh[i]
    zx = get(zh[i],'XData')
    zy = get(zh[i],'YData')
```

I get this (first line is a result of the "print zh[i]" above):

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x048FDA70>]

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
  return self.func(*args)
...
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 1130, in getp
  func = getattr(obj, 'get_' + property)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_XData'
```

#### EDIT

I simplified the problem down to this:

```
new_handler = plt.plot(0.5, 0, 'go', ms=10)
plt.setp(new_handler, markersize=10.0, markeredgewidth=1.0,markeredgecolor='k',markerfacecolor='g',picker=5)
print plt.getp(new_handler,'xdata')
```

Still same error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_xdata'
```

Comment: print plt.getp(new_handler) -- and see what results. Does newhandler contain what you think it does? Does that help you trace back to see the problem?

Comment: It returns "xdata = [0.5]" as one of the possible properties to be retrieved.

Comment: Note the completely revised solution below. There were two errors in the code: (a) the assignment to `new_handler` had a comma missing and (b) the ways of reading the properties from a`Line2D` object use the `get_data()` method, not `getp`.

Comment: Thanks very much! What really confused me was the fact that the error obviously was complaining that new_handler was a list, but I didn't know how to "cast" it so that it wasn't a list anymore. The comma is the solution I was looking for. 

Interestingly, this (quite common, I assume) mistake also demonstrates one of the downsides of python - since the variable types are not explicitly defined, the interpreter might interpret the variable assignment in an unexpected way! Something I'll definitely keep in mind in the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plot returns a list, therefore we must have a COMMA after new_handler
new_handler, = plt.plot(0.5, 0, 'go', ms=10)

# new_handler now contains a Line2D object
# and the appropriate way to get data from it is therefore:
xdata, ydata = new_handler.get_data()
print xdata

# output:
# [ 0.5]
```

The answer was hidden in the [Line2D API documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html?highlight=line2d#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) -- I hope this helps.

Comment: I want the user to be able to move the point plotted around on the graph. z[i] is the initial position of the point in the plot. I need to save a pointer to that object instance, so that later on, once it has been moved, I can retrieve the new XData and YData. Am I plotting the point correctly in the first place? (Is what i've described above even possible in python?)

Comment: I discovered that I probably should be doing this: zx = plt.getp(z[i],'xdata'), although it still complains that it's a list.

Comment: I've edited the post to include a simpler version of the problem. See the EDIT section.

Comment: I receive a TypeError when I try to instantiate one of these in exactly this way. It claims that is a NoneType, and thus not iterable.

Comment: Can you put up your problem as a question? Show your code as it is not clear that this code snippet could lead to the error you describe.